# Can the pitcher run to first base

Tags: rules, baseball

can the pitcher run to first base with the ball and get an out?

Comment: In what circumstances? There's more than just "have the ball and go somewhere".

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It doesn't matter how the ball gets to the base, if a player touches the base with control of the ball before the runner gets there, the runner is out. The pitcher could throw, kick, or roll the ball to first if they wanted to. On rare occasions, the ball will get stuck in their glove so a pitcher will throw their entire glove (with the ball inside) over to first base!

Answer (score 0):

If they beat the runner there then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can.
This occurs in many instances:
The ball is hit to the pitcher and the pitcher beats the runner to the bag
Pitchers also assist in run downs, and if any defensive player beats the batter to the first base bag, it is an out